How to show previous weeks on power bi
hope you are having an amazing day
I'm currently working on a power bi report, I'll give you a few context about it
I have a dataset where I have every downtime record for a company with the total of downtime in minutes for each record, also I have the datetime and the fiscal week
So I need to add a single select slicer where I can choose the week that I want to filter and in a bar chart display the downtime sum for the week selected and the downtime for the past 4 weeks (one bar for each week)
I've been trying and I haven't found a solution so I hope some of you could help me please.
Regards!

I dont have the full context (table names etc.) but based off your requirement, I think you could make use of the WEEKNUM function in PBI.
= WEEKNUM(datetime_column, 2) -- if your week starts on Monday
= WEEKNUM(datetime_column, 2) -- if your week starts on Sunday
So your dax query would essentially be:
SumPreviousFourWeeks =
VAR CurrentWeek = WEEKNUM(MAX(YourTable[datetime_column]), 2)  // 2 for Monday as start of the week
VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(MAX(YourTable[datetime_column]))
RETURN
CALCULATE(
SUM(YourTable[YourValueColumn]),
FILTER(
YourTable,
WEEKNUM(YourTable[datetime_column], 2) >= CurrentWeek - 4 &&
WEEKNUM(YourTable[datetime_column], 2) < CurrentWeek &&
YEAR(YourTable[datetime_column]) = CurrentYear
)
)
